# Find the customers who bought ProductA in any month and then bought ProductB in the immediate next month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Consider this table,

```
CREATE TABLE ProductSale 
(
     cust INT,
     [Month] INT, 
     amt INT,
     product VARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO ProductSale (cust, Month, amt, product) 
VALUES (103, 11, 493, 'pizza'), (103, 12, 304, 'drink'),
       (103, 10, 189, 'drink'), (100, 12, 270, 'pizza'),
       (100, 11, 187, 'drink'), (102, 8, 378, 'drink'),
       (101, 10, 490, 'drink'), (101, 9, 123, 'Pizza')
```

Customer buy one product in a month and followup with buying another product next month.

I would like to get records of customers who bought Pizza in any month and then bought drink in the immediate next month.

For example, 103 is such customer. 100 looks like one, but he is not.

How can I achieve this using a SQL query?

Comment: SO is **not** a code-writing service - so please show us what **YOU** have tried so far. Where are you stuck? What results (if any) are you getting so far??

Comment: Hint : `NOT EXISTS()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may achieve this by using `cross apply`.

```
select p.* from ProductSale as p 
cross apply ( 
    select * from ProductSale as ps 
    where p.cust=ps.cust 
    and p.month+1=ps.month 
    and ps.product = 'drink' 
    and p.product='pizza' ) as pg
```